# Spring Security .hasAnyRole doesn't work, 403 Forbidden

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, http-status-code-403

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    
    private final LogoutHandler logoutHandler;
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/sign/**")
            .permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole(Role.ADMIN.name())
            .requestMatchers("/trainer/**").hasAnyRole(Role.TRAINER.name())
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
            .logoutSuccessHandler(
                    (request, response, authentication) -> 
                    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext());
            
        return http.build();
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationService {
    
    private final AdminRepo adminRepo;
    
    private final UserRepo repository;
    
    private final TokenRepo tokenRepo;
    
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    private final JwtService jwtService;
    
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthenticationResponse register(RegisterRequest request) {
        var user = User.builder()
                .firstname(request.getFirstname())
                .lastname(request.getLastname())
                .username(request.getUsername())
                .birthdate(request.getBirthdate())
                .email(request.getEmail())
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(request.getPassword()))
                .role(request.getRole())
                .build();
        if(request.getRole() == Role.ADMIN) {
            Admin admin = new Admin();
            user.setAdmin(admin);
        } else if(request.getRole() == Role.TRAINER) {
            Trainer trainer = new Trainer();
            user.setTrainer(trainer);
        }
        var savedUser = repository.save(user);
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        saveUserToken(savedUser, jwtToken);
        return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .token(jwtToken)
                .build();
    }
    

    public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request) {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                request.getEmail(),
                request.getPassword()
            )
        );

        var user  = repository.findByEmail(request.getEmail())
            .orElseThrow();

        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        revokedAllUserTokens(user);
        saveUserToken(user, jwtToken);

        return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
            .token(jwtToken)
            .build();
    }
    
    public void revokedAllUserTokens(User user) {
        var validUserTokens = tokenRepo.findAllValidTokensByUser(user.getId());
        if (validUserTokens.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        } else {
            validUserTokens.forEach(t -> {
                t.setExpired(true);
                t.setRevoked(true);
            });
            tokenRepo.saveAll(validUserTokens);
        }
    }
    
    private void saveUserToken(User user, String jwtToken) {
        var token = Token.builder()
                .user(user)
                .token(jwtToken)
                .tokenType(TokenType.BEARER)
                .revoked(false)
                .expired(false)
                .build();
        tokenRepo.save(token);
    }
}


@Service
public class JwtService {
    
    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "404E635266556A586E3272357538782F413F4428472B4B6250645367566B5970";
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }
    
    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }
    
    public String generateToken(UserDetailsImpl userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> extraClaims = new HashMap<>();
        extraClaims.put("id :", userService.getRoleIdFromUserId(userDetails.getId()));
        extraClaims.put("role", userDetails.getAuthorities().stream().findFirst().get().getAuthority());
        return generateToken(extraClaims, userDetails);
    }
    
    public String generateToken(
            Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
            UserDetailsImpl userDetails
            ) {
        return Jwts
                .builder()
                .setClaims(extraClaims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L ))
                .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }
    
    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token);
    }
    
    public boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        try {
            return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.
                parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Key getSignInKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }

}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/trainer")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TrainerController {
    
    private final UserService userService;
    
    private final TrainerService trainerService;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("ca marche");
    }
}

public enum Role {
    
    ADMIN,
    TRAINER
}
```

So first i did POST http://localhost:8082/sign/in because i've already sign up an trainer and i've get my token and then i did a GET http://localhost:8082/trainer/test with my token bearer authorization but i get Staus 403 Forbidden and in my console :
o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Responding with 403 status code
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /error
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access

Can someone help me ?

Comment: JWTs should not be used as sessions at all, there is a reason to why this type of authentication does not exist in spring security. Please read the spring security documentation on how to build proper security as this is some home made made up security solution. JWTs should not be handed out to browsers. At all.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but i dont understand why the JWT token should not be handed out to browsers ? So you think i should not use JWT and use another way to authenticate ? like what ?

Comment: read this question and answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77591848/spring-security-6-use-jwt-tokens-instead-of-jsessionid-after-oauth2-login as said before, please read the spring security documentation i cant teach you security thats not the job of stack overflow

Answer (score -1):

**Why 403 Forbidden :**

- All request is SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS and you did not update SecurityContextHolder as authenticated before going to controller test action

**How we can solve :**

- you have to extend OncePerRequestFilter and simulate authentication when valid username extracted from jwt token

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;

        final String username;

        if(authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);

        username = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

}
```

Comment: please read my comment on the question, JWTs should not be used this way, and answering this question like this encourages poor security, downvoted.

Comment: hi thank you so much for your comment , you configure sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS), so everything related to security will be from your jwt token. what i answer is not my invention. will give you few reference  link in a while

Comment: I beleave above all are reliable resource, after observation kindly share your thought

Comment: none of them are reliable sources, random bloggers. Okta the security company https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens Redis: https://redis.com/blog/json-web-tokens-jwt-are-dangerous-for-user-sessions/ OWASP: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_for_Java_Cheat_Sheet.html Spring Securities own recommendations https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297 ietf oauth2 best practices https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics please do proper research than read random blogs

Comment: geeksforgeeks.org, Java Brains are not some random bloggers. oauth2 and jwt both are the option when we work with STATELESS policy but none of them are best compare to in-build session. it is true oauth2 have better security and performance. question was related to jwt thats why my answer was also related to jwt. Thanks to educate me  and giving you an upvote to your last comment.

Comment: Java Brains is a youtube channel, so yes he is a random blogger, please show me his CV to prove otherwise. I am very well aware of him and all he does is that he is productive in putting out a lot of videos. That does not mean that his information is always correct. Productive does not in anywaay mean correct. geeksforgeeks.org is a site where anyone can submit an article, without any type of proof reading, so yes they are both unreliable sources that should be viewed with critical eyes. I trust OWASP a lot more than your sources https://owasp.org/about/

Comment: also the java brains video you linked to is 4 years old, its is using an outdated version of spring security, and even if it portrayed correct implementation at the time (which it doesnt), security evolves, since malicious actors come up with new clever ways to break things. So the video is also extremely outdated.

Comment: Thank you so much for observation and proper information

Comment: And to comment on your stateless comment. STATELESS security is never applied to browser clients, statelessness is used between the browser client and when fetching resources from resource servers, by leveraging an exchange proxy switching the cookies to a JWT to be used within private networks to avoid additional introspection calls to the issuer to verify tokens. The implicit grant has been deprecated, JWTs should not be handed out to browsers unless you are prepared to accept all the risks attached to it, and you find those risks acceptable.

Comment: “JWT to be used within private networks”, definitely I’ll explorer this topic more. Could you please tell, is it safe in public network to use jwt + authentication server  (is valid check)  when consume resource from a microservice end point.

Comment: as i explained, on the public internet, you should only use cookies to communicate between your brwser clients and your backend. JWTs are to be used only within private networks to communicate between microservices. Read about the BFF pattern and the Open ID Connect standard.

Comment: Backend for Frontend (BFF) , thank you so much for this valuable information.