# springboot app deploy as war on external tomcat works but not embeded tomcat issues 403

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security

I have a springboot 3.2.2 packaged as WAR file and deployed into external tomcat v10.1.18 and I am able to access my controller via postman and via my angular application, however the same app when run from embeded tomcat v10.1.18 from intellij or eclipse, fails with 403 error from angular app and postman, weird behavior usually the failure should be other way around, are there any security upgrades causing this issue?

following are the server debug logs

```
21:46:47.590 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
21:46:47.590 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
21:46:47.590 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
21:46:47.590 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
21:46:47.590 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected FixedThemeResolver
21:46:47.591 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@6fe243a
21:46:47.591 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@575c23f1
21:46:47.591 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
21:46:47.591 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 1 ms
21:46:47.602 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing POST /api/v1/sayHello
21:46:47.615 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
21:46:47.615 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.SessionManagementFilter - Request requested invalid session id F116C9F04B2809C02E15348F58666EFA
21:46:47.616 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint - Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
21:46:47.623 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing POST /error
21:46:47.623 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
21:46:47.623 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint - Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

> SecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .cors(httpSecurityCorsConfigurer -> httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.requestMatchers("/api/v1/**")
                    .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
            .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider()).addFilterBefore(
                    jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
    corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(3600L);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
    return source;
}
```

> Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xpo.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapgs</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>mapgs api</name>
    <description>mapgs API</description>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.xpo.api.Application</start-class>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: First of all handing out JWT to browsers is dangerous, and spring security has made active choice to not have that type of authentication so i dont understand why you have built some custom jwtfilter. Custom security is in general bad practice. Second is that you are doing a request that fails and is redirected to the `/error` endpoint all in accordance to the error handling in spring boot, that you have not permitted så you get a 403. So you need to permit to see your actual error.

Comment: @Toerktumlare thank you for the comment, we are upgrading our front end application to angular which need to deal with jwt tokens, hence replaced username/password authentication with jwt token which generated with combination key+user credentials. If you have any references to implement single page application with username/password and without handing out jwt to browsers?

Comment: you instead set up an issuer and implement OpenID connect, together with BFF server. Or you just implement standard cookie based authentication using FormLogin.

Comment: OpenID connect is out of our solution equation as previous app lived with db based authentication and we were ordered to upgrade our ui with angular. As you mentioned i need to see angular with cookie based authentication

Comment: You asked for suggestions and when i presented suggestions you changed the requirements so i will not present any more suggestions, i advice you to read this answer i have written here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77592667/1840146 and understand that _resource owner password grant_ https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#name-resource-owner-password-cre MUST NOT be buildt and _implicit grant_ SHOULD NOT be built https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#name-implicit-grant

Comment: These are also the recommendations for SPA applications by the spring team https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297 good luck

Comment: See this article I wrote for a reference for authorizing an Angular app with OAuth2: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2 To use OAuth2, you'll have to connect an authorization server to your existing database (you can do that at least with Keycloak and Spring Authorization Server)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the context path which is set when deployed as WAR into external tomcat and all my controllers/security config unaware of the path definition hence resulting 403. I have set the context-path to work with local and support to deploy into external tomcat

```
server.servlet.context-path=/mapgs
```