Spring Boot redirection back to login page
I am using Spring Boot and authorization server,
This is my application.yml security section:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          auth0:
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:5556/auth0/auth
            token-uri: http://localhost:5556/auth0/token
            jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:5556/auth0/keys
        registration:
          auth0:
            client-id: sample-app
            client-secret: ZXhhbXBsZS1hcHAtc2VjcmV0
            client-name: Sample App
            scope: openid
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8085/callback

and this is my filter chain:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/callback").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
        
    }
}

When I open my browser, type in one of my Spring Boot GET endpoints, I see login page asking for username/password. I type them in, press "Login" and see button "Grant access". I press it and see endpoint response.
But subsequent requests to endpoints do not contain any bearer token. Shouldn't there be a token in the headers, once I authorize?

Could you verify if Dex is issuing tokens correctly ? Normally tokens returned are in Authorization Bearer token.

@Beck-воин, this command: curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:5556/dex/token' returns tokens successfully (with appropriate headers set)

response is: {"access_token":"zbhk65col5ctgfpayurjrz73o","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":86399,"id_token":"..."}

Then this is what is important, is that you get the bearer token. OAuth in Authorization code works in the following :
1- Authenticate with authorization server
2- Get the bearer token.
3- redirection
4- Authentication using the bearer token
5- Access resource server.

I understand, but there is no bearer in the headers, I can access my GET endpoints without any tokens. When I press "Grant access", I see a bunch of 302/303 redirections, and eventually my GET endpoint is called successfully, without any token

Apparently what you are missing is the oAuth token check. First steps are correct to get the token, however you need this. This checks the token received by the authorization server before accessing the resource server. resourceserver: jwt: jwk-set-uri: localhost:5556/dex/keys In you application.yaml file.

@Beck-воин could you please check the last part of my post, I added resourceserver.jwt settings into application.yaml but still don't see any tokens in requests. (and postman requests WITH tokens always get redirected to login page)

Could you please check the answer i posted ? Normally what is missing is token check in the SecurityConfig. (Considering you choose to use Jwt algorithm),

What is missing is the oAuthCheck in SecurityConfig
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationConverter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login/oauth2/code/dex").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2Login()
                .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
    }

    private JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtAuthenticationConverter converter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        // Customize the converter if needed
        return converter;
    }
}


It worked, thanks a lot!

fun fact here: the token wasn't in the headers because that's how spring security works - it gets a token from authorization service, creates JSESSIONID out of it, and sends it back to the browser. The browser stores JSESSIONID in the cookies and includes it into every request header (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77591848/spring-security-6-use-jwt-tokens-instead-of-jsessionid-after-oauth2-login)

but my spring filter chain was still not processing jwt properly so jwt tokens in the request were completely ignored, that's why it was working in the browser but not in http clients like postman or cURL

Yes, it includes the JSESSIONID, but Authorization header with Bearer token is necessary to access resource service,  otherwise there is no oAuth.

yes, or JSESSIONID instead of token. I mean, for example in postman or cURL, if I don't add any token in the request, but add a valid JSESSIONID, then it gets HTTP 200 from endpoints (not sure if this is expected or not though, I think it is)

Yes you are right, because JSESSIONID is a cookie that identifies active session from a successfully authenticated token.
